# Jasmine, Angular, and Resharper: Trouble injecting a controller in a unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, resharper

I'm having trouble injecting an angular controller into my jasmine spec file.  The error begins with `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/modulerr...`

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8.2.3.  Here are relevant snippets:

**Jasmine**

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-core/angular.min.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/angular-core/angular-mocks.js" />

/// <reference path="~/Scripts/angular-controllers/FormsAdminSecurityAccountAdmin.js" />

describe("Sec Acct Admin Controller", function () {
    var $controllerConstructor, scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(module('accounts'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controllerConstructor = $controller;
        ctrl = $controllerConstructor('accountsCtrl', { $scope: scope });
    }));

    it("the controller is present", function () {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module('accounts', ['cocUtilities', 'angucomplete-alt', 'ui.date', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns']);

angular.module('accounts').config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {      // Allows $location to parse the arguments to a URL
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
}]);

angular.module('accounts').controller('accountsCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', 'dataFactory', 'cccsLookupForAccounts', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $window, $location, dataFactory, cccsLookupForAccounts, uiGridConstants) { ... }
```

Finally, I was able to get a simplified version of this to work using test spec and angular files.  The problem seems to be injecting this particular module/controller, but I haven't been able to find the problem.  I'd be grateful for any help you can provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had not included the needed files at the top of the spec file.  The module I was trying test has dependencies, and the test runner couldn't find them because I hadn't included the correct `<reference path=...` for the files that had the dependencies.  When I added those, it worked.